# Requiring namespace as a string

Tags: npm, clojurescript

I'm having issues when using `:require` on a namespace that needs to be a string:

```
Assert failed: cljs.analyzer/foreign-dep? expected symbol got "@0xproject/connect"
(symbol? dep)
```

Repository that reproduces the problem (cab be run with e.g. `lein figwheel dev`):

https://github.com/fbielejec/npm-deps-demo

Comment: upgraded to 1.10.191 and code could be compiled, but don't know it is working or not

Comment: it compiled before too, the problem happens during runtime.